# Macro to save and version control file

Tags: excel, vba

I want the macro to save my Excel file, but to check first if a file with the same name already exists. If yes, then macro to save the file with a version after. E.g. if Testworkbook.xls already exists, then macro to save the new file as Testworkbook_v1.xls and so on. Below is the code that I tried but it's giving an error.

```
Sub SaveAs()    
    ChDir "C:\Documents and Settings\Sae\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Documents and Settings\Sae\Testworkbook" & v + 1 & ".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will work whenever you save the workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim filePath As String, wbName As String, version As Integer

    filePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\Sae\Desktop" //Change as appropriate
    wbName = "Testworkbook - v"

    If Dir(filePath & Application.PathSeparator & ThisWorkbook.Name) = "" Then // Workbook does not exist
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath & Application.PathSeparator & wbName & 1
    Else
        version = CInt(VBA.Right$(VBA.Left$(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4), VBA.Len(VBA.Left$(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4)) - Len(wbName))) + 1
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath & Application.PathSeparator & wbName & version
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this assumes that `.xls` is the file extension

Comment: how would you change it to save as .xlsm?

Comment: In the `SaveAs` method specify the file format using `fileformat:=52`. Note that 52 is the defined constant for `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` in Excel 2007+

Comment: Excellent! Rather frustrating writing a macro that automatically deletes all code from itself @.@

Answer (score 0):

[Dir()](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Basic_file_and_folder_examples_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/443.html) will help you determine if a file exists already.

[Workbook.SaveAs()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) will help you save the file out.

You'll need to concatenate your strings together with the `&` operator (to add on the `V1`).

**Edit:**

Thanks for posting what you have.  I came up with

```
Sub SaveNumberedFile()

    Static count As Integer
    Dim filestr As String
    filestr = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Code\TestWkbk"
    ThisWorkbook.Activate 'Activate whichever workbook you need
    If count = 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (filestr & ".xls")

    ElseIf count > 0 And Dir(filestr & "v" & count - 1 & ".xls") = "" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (filestr & "v" & count & ".xls")
    End If

    count = count + 1

End Sub
```

I used a static variable to keep track of the numbers.  This will retain the value of `count` between calls to the macro.  It will not keep track of `count` after you close the workbook.  In that situation, you can check to see what the last file number was using the `Dir()` command, and initialize the static variable to that value.

I did not add all of the frills to the `SaveAs` command, but you seem to know which ones you need.

Try it out, it may need some tweaking.